# UITableView under UISearchBar on MasterViewController (UISplitViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a problem when trying to add a search bar (UISearchController) on the header of the table of MasterViewController. 
[image: Initial state]
[image: Search selected]
As you can see, the table is getting under the search bar.
Any ideas on how can I fix this?

Here is the code that I use for the MasterViewController

```
private var searchController : UISearchController = ( {
    let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    return controller
})()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `definesPresentationContext = true` for your `searchController`

Comment: I've tried that and nothing happened. I think that the problem is on the `UISplitViewController`, because I've used that code on a `UITableViewController` on iPhone and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Open your storyboard, select your view controller and in **attributes inspector**, uncheck `Under Top Bars` in **View Controller group**